# CruiseControl.rb: Test fails, but build passes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cruisecontrol, cruisecontrol.rb

I'm using CruiseControl.rb (2.0.0pre1) for CI with a Rails 3 app and I'm trying to get it to work with rspec. Inside the `cruise_control.rb` I'm calling the spec rake task

```
Project.configure do |project|
 project.rake_task = 'spec'
end
```

Very basic and easy configuration. But even when a test is failing, the build passes. It doesn't detect wether the tests passes or fail.

Furthermore I want to know if I can grab the exit status from the rake task, and call a ruby script depending if a build fails or passes.

Comment: I tried it with ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3, same error

Comment: Hi. Did you find out the way to grab exit status from the rake task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that it was an error in Rails 3.2.1. The status code returned from the tests was always 0. (see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4923 and http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/abe4a8d070d069f24f7befd9a8da25c40f4c2a6d). Upgrading to Rails 3.2.2.rc1 fixed the problem.